# incorporating pagination in ajax json

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a ajax json retrieving all query results in a div.I'm not sure how to introduce pagination though.

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var hdnIds = document.getElementById('<%= HiddenField1.ClientID %>').value;

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "WebService1.asmx/GetEmployees",
                data: "{userid: " + JSON.stringify(hdnIds) + " }",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (list) {
                    $("#Something").append("<ul id='bullets' class='ul1'></ul>");
                    for (i = 0; i < list.d.length; i++) {
                        $("#bullets").append("<li class='li1'>"
                            + "<div style='float:left; width:20%'>"
                            + "<img  id='image' src='Handler3.ashx?id=" + list.d[i].id + "' />"
                            + "<p style='margin-left:2px; position:relative;color:DodgerBlue;font-size:small; font-style:bold'>" + list.d[i].UserName + "</p>"
                            + "<p style='margin-left:2px; position:relative;color:DodgerBlue;font-size:small'>" + list.d[i].Created_on + "</p>"
                            + "</div>"
                            + "<div style='float:left; width:80%'>"
                            + "<p class='p11'>" + list.d[i].Statusmes + "</p>"
                            + "</div>"                        
                            + "</li>");
                    } 
                },
                error: function (e) {
                    $("#Something").html("There was an error retrieving records");
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

And html as

```
 <div id="Something"></div>
```

ANy help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean by pagination? Do you want each of the AJAX requests to be placed in a separate div/block?

Comment: Yes. that is correct!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you already know about append which is what you need, but you need to change all your ids to classes since there will be more than 1 of them. Then, put all of the html you want to append into a string and just append that html.

```
HTML:
<div id = "parent">
    <div class = "Something"></div>
</div>


JAVASCRIPT (replace to the success AJAX call):
var htmlList = "<div class = "Something"><ul class='bullets ul1'>";                    

for (i = 0; i < list.d.length; i++) {
    htmlList += "<li class='li1'>"
    + "<div style='float:left; width:20%'>"
    + "<img  id='image' src='Handler3.ashx?id=" + list.d[i].id + "' />"
    + "<p style='margin-left:2px; position:relative;color:DodgerBlue;font-size:small; font-style:bold'>" + list.d[i].UserName + "</p>"
    + "<p style='margin-left:2px; position:relative;color:DodgerBlue;font-size:small'>" + list.d[i].Created_on + "</p>"
    + "</div>"
    + "<div style='float:left; width:80%'>"
    + "<p class='p11'>" + list.d[i].Statusmes + "</p>"
    + "</div>"                        
    + "</li>");
} 

htmlList += "</ul></div>";

$("#parent").append(htmlList);
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Sorry i Ive explained my problem correctly. I'm not so conversant with jquery ajax and json. I'm trying to achieve a set of ~10 results per page and let user to navigate to others pages as necessary.

Comment: this answer has nothing to do with pagination

Answer (score 1):

First, I would read up on javascript templating. There are a lot of libraries out there that will allow you to remove the bloated html code from your JS code so that it's easier to manage. Something like this: https://github.com/BorisMoore/jquery-tmpl.

After that, you should put the responsibility of pagination on the server side and let the JS/Ajax handle the calls to retrieve the data set. For instance:

```
//server side
var start = request.params.start //retrieve start index for data set
var limit = request.params.limit //retrieve max number of data set size

return db.Model.find({start: start, limit: limit, ...})


//client side JS/Ajax

//load first page 0-9
$.ajax({
  url: '/my/data/url',
  params: {
    start: 0, //start at first record in db
    limit: 10 //only return 10 results
  }
}).success(function(data) {
   //render data set using template
   $.template('#my-data-template', data).renderTo('#someDiv');
});

//load second page 10-19
$.ajax({
  url: '/my/data/url',
  params: {
    start: 10, //start at nth record in db
    limit: 10 //only return 10 results
  }
}).success(function(data) {
   //render data set using template
   $.template('#my-data-template', data).renderTo('#someDiv');
});
```

Comment: Is there no other straight solution? I'm trying to implement something similar to facebook, twitter like auto paging. I want to show first 10 results and a "load more" results tab to show next set of records and so on. However, the reason I'm using ajax json data is what I cannot find a way to deploy this functionality.

Comment: This is the straightest solution I can propose given the information provided. How you implement this is up to you. You can easily achieve Infinite scroll (a la Twitter) or a Load More option using javascript to handle the button click event and applying the code I presented above. I only hardcoded the start/limit options to help you understand the point, but this would be more dynamic in a real implementation.